# Pass value to controller in Spring MVC, what is the difference?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web

When I read some codes written with Spring MVC in an old project, I notice that the author using two similar method to pass value to controller as follows:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/print")
    public String PrintInfo(@RequestParam("name") String name,@RequestParam("age") int age) {
.......
}
```

Or

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/print")
    public String PrintInfo(String name,int age) {
.......
}
```

Both them work well.
The difference is whether it use the @RequestParam.

So what's the main difference between them? Which one is better, and why?

Comment: sounds like you already have the answer!

Answer (score 4):

This basically sounds to me like you're asking "what is a `RequestParam` and why should I use it?"

The [RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) allows you to bind the method parameter argument to the web request parameter.  Without any other attributes, your example tells Spring that a `name` and `age` parameter are required and Spring will know to associate those two parameters against the incoming request.  You can optionally set `required` to `false` to, well, make the argument optional:

```
public String PrintInfo(@RequestParam("name", required = false) String name,
                        @RequestParam("age") int age) {
```

As an extremely useful feature, you can also provide a `defaultValue` in case you receive an empty value from the request. So you can do:

```
public String PrintInfo(@RequestParam("name", defaultValue="John Doe") String name,
                        @RequestParam("age") int age) {
```

...and you'll never deal with a null name.

Finally, using it also does some magic type conversions, like for example automatically using an `Integer` type.  In your example, you could have used:

```
public String PrintInfo(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                        @RequestParam("age") Integer age) {
```

...and Spring would have boxed it automatically without you doing any extra work.

There's nothing inherently wrong with leaving off the `RequestParam` annotation, but you're essentially saying no to Spring enabling these features as you have in your second case.

Aside:

`@RequestMapping(value="/print")` can be more simply written as `@RequestMapping("/print")`

Answer (score 1):

If the *name of request parameter* and the *name of method arguments* will be equal, then Spring will bind parameters automatically by names. For example, you have incoming `GET` request:

```
http://localhost:8080/print?name=somename&age=30
```

And controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/print")
public String PrintInfo(String name,int age) {
    ...
}
```

In this case you don't need to specify `@RequestParam` annotation for parameter. Because names in request and names of methods args are equals.

---

But when names are not equals, then you need to specify the correspondence of names explicitly with `@RequestParam`. For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/print?user_name=somename&user_age=30
```

And controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/print")
public String PrintInfo(@RequestParam("user_name") String userName, @RequestParam("user_age")int userAge) {
    ...
}
```

So `@RequestParam` needed to help the Spring make bindings properly, when request param names and method args names are different.

---

Acutally, many developers always use `@RequestParam` even when names are equal. For example empty `@RequestParam`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/print")
public String PrintInfo(@RequestParam() String name, @RequestParam() int age) {
    ...
}
```

Because this annotation shows that argument comes from request and makes your code more clear and readable.